# Having HAProxy check back-end server status?

Tags: linux, high-availability, haproxy

`HAProxy` is able to load balance MySQL/TOMCAT/Cassandra/LDAP/WEB Server etc....perfectly.
The main issue is how to make sure that the backend MySQL/TOMCAT/Cassandra etc server to forward the request to is up and running 
(I mean not just to establish a connection to port 3306 for mysql,8080 for tomcat,389 for LDAP etc.
I mean something more “**COMPLETE**”, that performs a little operation against Back-end Servers).

**My Use Case :

=============**

There are numerous back-end tomcat working behind `HAproxy` , All tomcat is serving through `HAproxy` and suddenly one of tomcat is gone `OutOfMemory`.
Apparently for `Haproxy`, that tomcat server is Up , but request routed to that tomcat failing as tomcat running OOM.

Is it possible to make `Haproxy` check the status of a back-end Server using a small shell script?

What this script basically does is performs a basic operation against the tomcat then returns http status 200 
if the operation was successful or http status 500 if it there was any error (i.e. tomcat was not available).

Are there any other ways to configure `HAproxy` to check status "COMPLETE" rather than just connection check on **server-ip : port** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm using is available at this link: http://sysbible.org/2008/12/04/having-haproxy-check-mysql-status-through-a-xinetd-script/

It's a little too long to paste inline here, but to summarize, there is a small shell script which executes a simple query against the MySQL server on localhost and outputs an HTTP 200 or 500 response on success/failure respectively. There are a variety of ways to run this, but for simplicity the linked solution just registers the shell script directly as an xinetd service. Obviously this is a port that ideally should only be open to the HAProxy server, and definitely not open to the Internet!

HAProxy's built in HTTP monitoring, which is intended for monitoring web backends, can consume the output of this service and use it to determine if the server is actually up.